# Can you use fabricate to consume more raw material than the created object needs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you cast [fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) and target more raw materials than needed for what you create, what happens to the excess material (casting it on a 120ft cube of forest and turning it into a single chair)?

We want to clear out a wall perimeter in a forest, but we don't want the wood and leaves that would result from it, and we can't think of a way to dispose of it.

> Choose raw materials that you can see within range. You can fabricate a Large or smaller object (contained within a 10-foot cube, or eight connected 5-foot cubes), given a sufficient quantity of raw material.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is official guidance on it. The spell description itself doesn't suggest anything specific, saying only that you need a "sufficient quantity".

In my games the spell doesn't affect things that don't go into the thing that's being fabricated, though. If you need one chair's worth of wood, then that's all the wood that the spell directly affects and nothing at all happens to the rest of the forest. I've found this helpful specifically because it cuts down on unintended consequences.

Also of note: if your players want to clear a section of forest there's no need to try to cheat the spell with excess material to deal with. They can just make a 10x10x10 cube of wood, for example. If they don't care what happens to the wood that's as good as anything else they might make and then ignore.